# SSRS Reporting Deployment of Report on Local SSRS System1 with other System2(Development Server)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a question Regarding SSRS Reporting, Scenario is

I Have Two systems and i  Want to Make one as Reporting server say S1(all the Configurations   are Done Necessary to Make Reporting server) , now i want that i design my Reports on the 2nd system say S2 and deploy my report to the reports S1 which is database server What should be the Target URL for this in Business intelligent Studio in S2 System

Thanks in Advance i Need it Badly

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The URL for report management will be visible to you in the Reporting Services Configuration Manager. Exactly which URL are you wanting to see ? The report deployment URL -> if so, then this depends on your report folder structure, if you just need to know the root and structure of the root folder then REporting Services Configuration Manager is the place to look.